# TTF fonts in nodetext using cgSceneGraph

Tags: html, canvas, truetype

Is there a way to use TTF in text nodes? I saw that there is a setTypo method, but this gets only a font-family string, like Arial. Should I create in CSS a new font family and use this one?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the text extension provided with cgSceneGraph will accept a font-family String.
We could extend the node with such a new feature, but it will be complex for a small ROI.

A good and simple solution is to use CSS to create a font-family and then use it on the CGSGNodeText :

```
@font-custom {
    font-family: customNameForTheFont;
    src: url(myFolderWithFonts/font.ttf); 
}
```

TTF font will work with every CSS3 compliant browser. In case of an exotic framework accepting Canvas but not TTF font, don't forget to declare an EOT font (you can find converters on the web) :

```
@font-custom {
    font-family: customNameForTheFont;
    src: url(myFolderWithFonts/font.eot); 
}
```

and in your application you declare the font:

```
myTextNode.setTypo("customNameForTheFont");
```

Just remember that the typo is loaded asynchronously. You can avoid possible issues by pre-loading the font (use a div with an inline style using the font, use a loader class, ...).

Cheers.
Gwen.

Comment: Thank you Gwen for your reply. I just tried it and work just fine. I prefered to use as pre-loading a hidden div with text using the fonts, which doesn't give the feeling of "waiting" to the user, but transparently loads them.

Comment: Glad to read it's OK for you. I agree that a hidden div with inline style using the font is a good solution to  load custom font.